# Uicollection view dynamic height but fixed width

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working with UICollectionView I have 4 different kind of cells. Every cell is designed in xib file . when i load them in collection view it goes out of screen. i don't know why it is happening. Some cells have fixed height while some have dynamic height (depends on data coming from API). So is there any possible way to solve this issue. 
i have tried Estimate size automatic to dynamic

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let screenwidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenwidth-20)
}

func setSize () {
    let layout = mainCollection.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)}
```

}[image: screenshot of how end portion of cell is going out of screen]

Comment: Is `awakeFromNib()` being called? Add a `print("awake")` statement in there to confirm.

Comment: Can you check in the `Size Inspector` and play with `Autoresizing` red arrows/lines?

Comment: yes i tried but no effect on view

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
let screenWidth = self.CollecionView.frame.width
```